# PHP CS Fixer won't load .php-cs file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, php-cs-fixer

I downloaded and installed PHP CS Fixer extension for VSCode (by junstyle) and the official php-cs-fixer-v2.phar file from https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer. I created a file named config.php-cs and pasted the reference config code in it :

```
return PhpCsFixer\Config::create()
    ->setRules(array(
        '@PSR2' => true,
        'array_indentation' => true,
         ....
```

I placed both those files in C:\wamp64\www\configuration_php\

Here is my settings.json

```
{
    "workbench.iconTheme": "file-icons",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "editor.lineHeight": 22,
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "editor.fontWeight": "400",
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.cursorStyle": "line",
    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 15,
    "javascript.validate.enable": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "files.autoSave": "off",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "editor.fontFamily": "JetBrains Mono, Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
    "editor.cursorBlinking": "smooth",
    "editor.formatOnSaveTimeout": 5000,
    "php-cs-fixer.executablePath": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\configuration_php\\php-cs-fixer-v2.phar",
    "php-cs-fixer.config": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\configuration_php\\config.php_cs",
    "php-cs-fixer.onsave": true,
}
```

I can tell my editor considers the executablePath because if I put a mistake in the path, I get an error message. The problem is for the config path. VSCode seems to be ignoring it completely and won't use the config file or raise any error if I introduce mistakes in the path or in the file content.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys I'm a potato, I wrote "php-cs" instead of "php_cs". Closed.